# How to apply Style in VBA to a textbox on a userform?

Tags: vba, ms-word, combobox, textbox, userform

I have this code for a textbox.

```
Dim TextBox15 As Range
   ActiveDocument.Variables("bmagicf").Value = Me.TextBox15.Value
   Me.TextBox15.Value = Me.TextBox15.Text
   
   With ActiveDocument

   .Fields.Update

   End With
```

How can I apply a style to it in the same sense as the code below?

```
    Dim ComboBox9 As Range
    Set ComboBox9 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bmagich").Range
    ComboBox9.Text = Me.ComboBox9.Value
    
    If Me.ComboBox9.Value = "No" Then
    ComboBox9.Text = "Appendices"
     ComboBox9.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Style 22")
    End If
```

I tried the code below but had no luck:

```
Dim TextBox15 As Range
    ActiveDocument.Variables("bmagicf").Value = Me.TextBox15.Value
    Me.TextBox15.Value = Me.TextBox15.Text
    Textbox15.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Style 22")
    With ActiveDocument

    .Fields.Update

    End With
```

Comment: You can't - most of the userform controls don't even have a style property. And if so (like the combobox) you definitly have to set other values than styles defined in the word-document - see: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/style-property

Answer (score 1):

Your question is extremely misleading, and your code is confusing.

From looking at your code it appears that you are ***not*** trying to apply a Style to a text box on a User Form, though the title of your question says you are.

Your code is confusing because you have used the same name for several different things.

Your code isn’t working because you have missed a line of code. Look again at the combo box example. The second line is crucial.

`Set ComboBox9 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bmagich").Range`

You need a line of code like that for your text box example, otherwise the `Range` variable, `TextBox15`, doesn’t point to anything.